# How to use UIViewPropertyAnimator with auto layout?

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiview, autolayout

All the examples I could find online for `UIViewPropertyAnimator` use views that are laid out by setting frame rather than using auto layout, which is how views are commonly laid out. When using auto layout, the view animates to the position I want, but afterwards I am not sure of how to set it back to its "model" position.

```
// Move a view that is constrained to the center of its superview
UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 1, curve: .linear) {
    testView.center = CGPoint(x: 10, y: 10)
}.startAnimation()
```

It apparently adds some kind of constraint? I logged the container view's constraints before and after performing the animation:

```
CONSTRAINTS BEFORE:
view: [<NSLayoutConstraint:0x618000094f00 UIView:0x7fd764004050.centerX == UIView:0x7fd75fd00000.centerX   (active)>, <NSLayoutConstraint:0x618000092de0 UIView:0x7fd764004050.centerY == UIView:0x7fd75fd00000.centerY   (active)>]

CONSTRAINTS AFTER:
view: [<NSLayoutConstraint:0x618000094f00 UIView:0x7fd764004050.centerX == UIView:0x7fd75fd00000.centerX   (active)>, <NSLayoutConstraint:0x618000092de0 UIView:0x7fd764004050.centerY == UIView:0x7fd75fd00000.centerY   (active)>, <NSLayoutConstraint:0x6100000922a0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' UIView:0x7fd75fd00000.height == 667   (active)>, <NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x610000092570 h=-&- v=-&- 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Left' UIView:0x7fd75fd00000.minX == 0   (active, names: '|':UIWindow:0x7fd75fc07110 )>, <NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x610000092890 h=-&- v=-&- 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Top' UIView:0x7fd75fd00000.minY == 0   (active, names: '|':UIWindow:0x7fd75fc07110 )>, <NSLayoutConstraint:0x610000091670 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' UIView:0x7fd75fd00000.width == 375   (active)>]
```

What's going on here? How should I handle the animation of views that are positioned with auto layout? Is Apple encouraging users to go back to frame-based layouts?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use `UIViewPropertyAnimator` with *Auto Layout*, but you need to modify the constraints instead of the view's frame and call `layoutIfNeeded()` inside of the closure.

**First example:  Animate by modifying constraint `constant`**

Create a view in the Storyboard.  Create a constraint to position the `centerX` of your view equal to the leading edge of the superview.  Create an `@IBOutlet` to that constraint and call it `centerXConstraint`.  Similarly, create a `centerYConstraint` that positions the `centerY` of your view equal to the top of its superview.  Both of these constraints should have `constant = 0`.

Create `@IBOutlet`s to the constraints:

```
@IBOutlet weak var centerXConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet weak var centerYConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

Set the `constant` values of the constraint to the new position and then call `view.layoutIfNeeded()` inside of `UIViewPropertyAnimator`:

```
// Make sure view has been laid out
view.layoutIfNeeded()

// Set new X and Y locations for the view
centerXConstraint.constant = 50
centerYConstraint.constant = 80

UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 1, curve: .easeInOut) {            
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}.startAnimation()
```

---

**Second example: Animate by activating new constraints**

Create a view in your Storyboard (for example `redView`) and create an `@IBOutlet` to it in your code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var redView: UIView!
```

Create `@IBOutlet`s to the constraints that control the position of your view

```
// Outlets to the constraints set in the Storyboard
@IBOutlet weak var topConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet weak var leadingConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

Then when it's time to animate:

```
// Make sure view has been laid out
view.layoutIfNeeded()

// Deactivate the old constraints
topConstraint.isActive = false
leadingConstraint.isActive = false

// Active new constraints that move view to the bottom right        
redView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
redView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

// Animate the change        
UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 1, curve: .easeInOut) {
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}.startAnimation()
```

---

> So how is this better than the old `UIView` animation blocks?

`UIViewPropertyAnimator` is an object that you can configure to control the animation in various ways.  Here is a complete example that demonstrates:

1. Starting an animation
2. Pausing an animation
3. Finding out the fraction of the animation that has completed and setting the slide value to that
4. Scrubbing through the animation with the slider

[image: Scrubbing animation demo]

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var redView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var centerXConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet weak var centerYConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet weak var slider: UISlider!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        slider.isHidden = true
    }

    var myAnimator: UIViewPropertyAnimator?

    @IBAction func startAnimation(_ sender: UIButton) {
        view.layoutIfNeeded()

        centerXConstraint.isActive = false
        centerYConstraint.isActive = false

        redView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true

        redView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

        myAnimator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 10, curve: .easeInOut) {

            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }

        myAnimator?.startAnimation()
    }

    @IBAction func pauseAnimation(_ sender: UIButton) {
        guard let myAnimator = myAnimator else { return }

        myAnimator.pauseAnimation()

        print("The animation is \(String(format: "%.1f", myAnimator.fractionComplete * 100))% complete")

        slider.value = Float(myAnimator.fractionComplete)
        slider.isHidden = false
    }

    @IBAction func scrub(_ sender: UISlider) {
        myAnimator?.fractionComplete = CGFloat(sender.value)
    }
}
```

Comment: This is just the same old method of UIView animation blocks. Isn't there any improvement? Also what are those generated constraints?

Comment: UIViewPropertyAnimator is an object that can be configured to allow the animation to be paused, reversed, etc. You can create your own curves for controlling the speed and much more.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking about the constraints. I was just demoing how you could apply new constraints to the view and animate that.

Comment: At the end of my question, I show that there are system generated constraints added to the view. Allowing you to animate on frame and generate these constraints seems like an intentional behavior. I'd like to understand it.

Comment: I don't think those constraints are anything you are expected to interact with. I updated my question to answer your "is there any improvement over UIView animation blocks" question.  Take a look.

Comment: I'm sorry I can't mark this as correct even though you put some time into it, but I will upvote. I did read the docs and watched the WWDC video, so I'm aware of scrubbing, custom timing functions, etc. I'm looking for improvements related to working with constraint-based layouts.

Comment: In your question, what do you mean by setting it back to its "model" position?  Do you mean where it was before the animation?

Comment: Yeah, they used that terminology in the WWDC video. I never heard it before either TBH.

Comment: @GoldenJoe I think the model position refers to the start position of the view. It has to do with how animations work in ios. The animations animate the view's layer and then when it completes the "model view" updates immediately that's the purpose of layoutIfNeeded.

Answer (score 0):

#### I made a tutorial for swift 4.1

Example app via github and full tutorial:
 http://eon.codes/blog/2018/05/15/Animating-with-constraints/

```
class AnimVC:UIViewController{


 lazy var square:Square = createSquare()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .green
        _ = square
    }
}
extension AnimVC{
    func createSquare() -> Square{
        let square = Square()
        square.backgroundColor = .orange
        self.view.addSubview(square)
        _ = {//Define constraints for Square
            square.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            let anchor = Constraint.anchor(square, to: view, align: .centerCenter, alignTo: .centerCenter)
            let size = Constraint.size(square, size: CGSize(width:100,height:100))
            square.anchor = anchor
            square.size = size
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([anchor.x,anchor.y,size.w,size.h])
        }()

        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:  #selector(handleTap))
        square.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
        return square
    }
    @objc func handleTap(_ sender:UITapGestureRecognizer){
        let newConstraint = {
            guard let oldAnchorConstraint = self.square.anchor else {fatalError("err posConstraint not available")}
            NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate([oldAnchorConstraint.x])
            let newAnchorConstraint = Constraint.anchor(self.square, to: self.view, align: .topLeft, alignTo: .topLeft, offset: CGPoint(x:0,y:0))
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([newAnchorConstraint.x])
            self.square.anchor?.x = newAnchorConstraint.x
        }
        let anim = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 0.3, curve: .easeOut, animations: {
            newConstraint()// ⚠️️ Set the new constraint goal
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()//⚠️️  Ask the parent view to update its layout
        })
        anim.startAnimation()
    }
}
class Square:UIView{
    var anchor:(x:NSLayoutConstraint,y:NSLayoutConstraint)?
    var size:(w:NSLayoutConstraint,h:NSLayoutConstraint)?
}
```