# UIView frame animation not updating subviews layout - UIViewPropertyAnimator

Tags: ios, swift, animation, autolayout, uiviewpropertyanimator

I am trying to to a simple frame animation with UIViewPropertyAnimator. If I animate the frame, it works great.

The problem arrives when you add subviews with autolayout constraints. Subviews frames are calculated at the beginning of the animation and changed immediately instead of being done as the animation progresses.

Any idea on how to animate subViews as the view frame changes?

```
let frameChange = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: duration, curve: .easeInOut) {
    animatableCustomView.frame = finalFrame
}

frameChange.startAnimation()
```

My custom view is just a view with an ImageView inside constrained to all 4 edges to its superview.

Comment: try calling `yourView.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()` and `yourView.updateConstraints()`

Comment: Would that be inside the animation block?

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44341283/how-to-use-uiviewpropertyanimator-with-auto-layout) related to what are you asking about?

Comment: None of those solutions work, sadly.

Comment: Same thing happens if you add a Label inside the view that is animating its frame and the label needs to change from one line to two.

Comment: remove your auto layout constraints and use autoresizing tool of Xcode to add constraints, it creates constraints at runtime.

Comment: Check my answer in this link(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45768584/how-to-align-uilabel-horizontally-with-the-profile-photo-image/45769836#45769836) to know how to use autoresizing tool briefly.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45422722/ios-autolayout-constraints-for-three-squares/45429247#45429247 - For more help to use autoresizing tool.

Comment: @CristianPena I'm having the same issue and stumbled across your question.  What did you end up doing for this?